# How to force delete an open file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, system-administration

Remove-Item command does not delete files which are in use. Is there any way where we can delete all the files irrespective of their state?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this is by finding the processes that are using the file then stop the processess.You can then delete the file after.

```
$allProcesses = Get-Process
#$lockedFile is the file path
foreach ($process in $allProcesses) { 
$process.Modules | where {$_.FileName -eq $lockedFile} | Stop-Process
-Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
Remove-Item $lockedFile
```

Comment: And what if the file is in a network drive, in use by other users in other machines? Is there a way to delete the file without stopping processes?