# How do I remove a folder from Powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm trying to delete an empty folder via Powershell. I can delete the folder manually w/o any issues but when I try to run the following PS command I get the error:

[image]

the PS command is `Remove-Item "C:\Program Files\P...Ware" -Force;`

---

### update

I followed @Captain's advise and still got the same error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may work for you:

```
$allProcesses = Get-Process
#$lockedFile is the file path
foreach ($process in $allProcesses) { 
$process.Modules | where {$_.FileName -eq $lockedFile} | Stop-Process
-Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
Remove-Item $lockedFile
```

from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45714289/10958914

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide the -path parameter as well

```
Remove-Item -path "yourfolder path" -force
```

Your command will be like this

```
Remove-Item -path "C:\Program Files\P...Ware" -Force;
```

Comment: Can you share what is the folder name because there might be some special character which might be creating issue ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Done Right Solutions\Pire

Comment: The file is in use as per the error message. Do you have any program running from that folder or using any files from that folder ??

Comment: thanks Manish, it worked per @Captain's response below. Thanks for the assistance! :-)